# android spinner background not transparent

Tags: android, background, spinner

I have a custom spinner which should display transparency in the background.Instead it shows white background.Below is the xml layout and the style of the spinner.
activity_main.xml:

```
 <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="MaterialBetterSpinner"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
 />
```

spinner_item.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_style">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item1"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Aizwal"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@drawable/marker2"></ImageView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

spinner_style.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
     />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"></solid>
    <stroke android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#903F51B5" />
    <corners android:radius="1dp"
        />
</shape>
```

Comment: post your color xml code

Comment: <resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#8C9EFF</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#903F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#ffffff</color>
</resources>

Comment: add code in spinner  android:background="#CCFF0000"

Comment: @sasikumar The color is similar to red

Comment: android:background=#0f0f0f

Comment: Hmm... Tried that before